# Where are the GUI Screenshot images saved in NetBeans

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am using NetBeans IDE which comes with a **GUI screenshot button** .

[image]

I take a screenshot using the **GUI screenshot button** and all i get is these

[image]

Where is these "Snapshot of " image saved on my computer ??

How do i save these image to my computer ???

Answer (score 0):

Urm, I don't think it is really an image - it just lets you inspect the Swing UI controls.